# All scheduled jobs disappeared

Tags: cron-job, scheduling

In my multi site installation all my scheduled jobs have disappeared. I don't know when, but most likely after an update.

Is there an easy way of restoring all the standard scheduled jobs that are created when installing CiviCRM?

I use CiviCRM 4.6.4 on Drupal 7 on a Debian Jessie server. The scheduled jobs must have vanished already on 4.5.*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All schedule job get saved against civicrm_job. So, by restoring civicrm_job table you can get all the schedule jobs back -

If you are looking for just the standard schedule jobs then try to install the same version of civicrm in different instance and copy the table content to your DB

Comment: And if you use logging, look in log_civicrm_job- it might even tell you when they were deleted.

Comment: Thanks! I took a look at the database and saw that the scheduled jobs were actually there, but invisible in the admin interface of CiviCRM, at least in the ones I looked in. As it it is a multi site installation - like I said - tHey are only visible in the first site, I mean the one I installed CiviCRM. But still I don't know: Is it a bug or feature. Do I have to create new jobs for the different sites? In the table there is a field for the site id, but why? All teh data are available in all sites, and that's the purpose of the multi site installation. So I'm still a bit confused.

Answer (score 2):

civicrm_job table has the Domain field in it. This means that the jobs are restricted to being seen only in the Domain that is referenced.
This is a 'feature' of using multisite.
It is possible to have multiple sites wired in to a single CRM without using Domains but can create issues in terms of user tables. Eg in Drupal you can get around this by using 'single sign on' but whether that is practical depends on the scenario. hope that helps